# Google OAuth2 OmniAuth Provider callback not working with GitLab behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, google-oauth, omniauth, gitlab, reverse-proxy

I've installed GitLab 8.0.2 on a VM, and I have an nginx reverse proxy set up to direct HTTP traffic to the VM. I am able to view the main login page for GitLab, but when I try to login using the Google OAuth2 method, the callback fails to log me in after entering my correct credentials. I simply get directed back to the GitLab login page.

Where might the problem be? The reverse proxy settings? GitLab settings (ie. Google OAuth config)?

Below is my nginx conf:

```
upstream gitlab  {
    server 192.168.122.134:80;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myserver.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab.error.log;
    root   /dev/null;

    ## send request back to gitlab ##
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://gitlab;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the old setup I had used iptables to redirect port 81 on the host machine to port 80 on the GitLab VM, and, in that case, the Google OAuth callback worked. I'd prefer to have people simply use standard port 80 for accessing my GitLab instance, though, so I want this reverse proxy method to work.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab 8.x has quite a few new things. Although I don't see anything specifically wrong with your `nginx.conf` file, it is pretty short compared to the example in the GitLab repository. Look through https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab-ssl to get an idea of the configuration you should consider adding.

Once your `nginx.conf` file is updated, read through GitLab [OmniAuth documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/integration/omniauth.html) and the Google OAuth2 integration documentation under 'Providers' on that OmniAuth page. Make sure you provide the correct callback URL to Google when registering.